# Is the File.url property defined by the File API specification?

Tags: html

As stated at http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/07/firefox-4-formdata-and-the-new-file-url-object/ it is, but I cannot file the definition in the spec...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it in the latest [editor's draft](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#file) either.    So I would treat it as very experimental.